# Use condition into a mySQL query

Tags: mysql, conditional-statements

I need to have a condition in my mySQL query base on the result of the query.

The `SELECT` returns me `IVC_Recipient` and I want to use this data to make a condition. But it doesn't work.

Here's the query:

```
SELECT 
    KDX_Id, 
    KDX_Name, 
    KDX_FirstName, 
    KDX_Company, 
    BOO_Id, 
    DEB_Date, 
    IFNULL(SUM(IVC_Sum + IVC_Taxes), 0) AS DEB_Total,
    DATEDIFF('2018-07-10', DEB_Date) AS DEB_Nb_Days,
    IVC_Recipient 
FROM ___Debtors 
JOIN ___Invoices 
    ON ___Invoices.IVC_Id = ___Debtors.DEB_InvoiceId 
JOIN ___Bookings 
    ON ___Bookings.BOO_Id = ___Invoices.IVC_BookingId


IF(IVC_Recipient = 'guest') {
    JOIN ___Kardex 
        ON ___Kardex.KDX_Id = ___Bookings.BOO_GuestId
}

IF(IVC_Recipient = 'company') {
    JOIN ___Kardex 
        ON ___Kardex.KDX_Id = ___Bookings.BOO_CompanyId
}
```

What I'm missing here please ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT 
    KDX_Id, 
    KDX_Name, 
    KDX_FirstName, 
    KDX_Company, 
    BOO_Id, 
    DEB_Date, 
    IFNULL(SUM(IVC_Sum + IVC_Taxes), 0) AS DEB_Total,  -- there is no GROUP BY
    DATEDIFF('2018-07-10', DEB_Date) AS DEB_Nb_Days,
    IVC_Recipient 
FROM ___Debtors 
JOIN ___Invoices 
    ON ___Invoices.IVC_Id = ___Debtors.DEB_InvoiceId 
JOIN ___Bookings 
    ON ___Bookings.BOO_Id = ___Invoices.IVC_BookingId
JOIN ___Kardex 
        ON ___Kardex.KDX_Id = (CASE 
             WHEN IVC_Recipient = 'guest' THEN  ___Bookings.BOO_GuestId
             WHEN IVC_Recipient = 'company' THEN ___Bookings.BOO_CompanyId
             END)
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much any "if" can be expressed as an AND in these situations:

```
JOIN ___Kardex 
    ON (IVC_Recipient = 'guest' AND ___Kardex.KDX_Id = ___Bookings.BOO_GuestId)
    OR (IVC_Recipient = 'company' AND ___Kardex.KDX_Id = ___Bookings.BOO_CompanyId)
```

...but depending on how index use works out, it can sometimes even just be more performant to join more simply and sort the results out later in the WHERE conditions (though this would be my last resort "can we get more speed this way" attempt).

```
JOIN ___Kardex 
    ON  ___Kardex.KDX_Id IN (___Bookings.BOO_GuestId, ___Bookings.BOO_CompanyId)
WHERE (IVC_Recipient = 'guest' AND ___Kardex.KDX_Id = ___Bookings.BOO_GuestId)
    OR (IVC_Recipient = 'company' AND ___Kardex.KDX_Id = ___Bookings.BOO_CompanyId)
```